# How authenticate for webservice with JMeter?

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I used JMeter as proxy to record all requests of a test scenario of our web services, and JMeter created request and one HTTP Authorization Manager, with stored authorizations for each request.

But when I launch this scenario, I get a 401 response code for all requests. I move HTTP Authorization manager in Thread Group, but I still get a 401 code.

All requests of our WS require authentication.

How do add authentication in one place for each request ? And, how parameterized them ?

Thanks, Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers may vary depending on web service security type and there are a lot of options, for example web service may require custom authentication header, custom HTTP header, custom cookie, custom token somewhere, etc.

- Exhibit A: request without authentication

  ```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
     <soap:Header/>
     <soap:Body>
        <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <web:CountryName>India</web:CountryName>
        </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
     </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  ```
- Exhibit B: request with username/password authentication

  ```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <soap:Header>
          <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true"
                         xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                         xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-29FBADA106D95AD8E114818886210611">
                  <wsse:Username>johndoe</wsse:Username>
                  <wsse:Password
                          Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
                      secret
                  </wsse:Password>
                  <wsse:Nonce
                          EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                      jnXB+PJ34M7aqfDU88glzg==
                  </wsse:Nonce>
                  <wsu:Created>2016-12-16T11:43:40.755Z</wsu:Created>
              </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
          <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <web:CountryName>India</web:CountryName>
          </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
      </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  ```

The most commonly used way of parametrizing a request is using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

See [Take the Pain out of Load Testing Secure Web Services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services) article for more detailed explanation of some web services authentication types bypassing in JMeter test.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, exactly that I need